# http request declared as deflate does not work

Tags: c#, http, request, deflate

I would like to make an HTTP request which contains compressed payload data.

The implementation of the `HttpContent` class looks like that:

```
public class DeflateJsonContent<T> : HttpContent
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _sink = new MemoryStream();

    public DeflateJsonContent(T model)
    {
        Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "deflate");

        using(var deflate = new DeflateStream(_sink, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            Json.Serialize(deflate, model, true);
        }

        _sink.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream destination, TransportContext context)
    {
        return _sink.CopyToAsync(destination);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = _sink.Length;
        return true;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _sink.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The request looks like this:

```
    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostDeflateJsonContentAsync(string uri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return _http.PostAsync(uri, content, token);
    }
```

When inspecting the communication using Fiddler I see that there is no 'deflate' in the request headers. Additionally Fiddler does not say that the request payload is compressed.

Did I miss something?

Comment: +1 for properly Disposing the `MemoryStream`

Answer (score -1):

Your client needs to send correct accept headers for deflate too; it's not just a server-side thing. See the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is not what I was asking for. I want to know how to make request compression work.Decompressing a compressed response is not of interest here.